# How can I get to Lille airport by public transport, avoiding the shuttle?

Tags: public-transport, airports, lille

I want to go to the Lille airport, but since I have enough time I would prefer taking a  regular bus rather than the shuttle. Google does not have public transport for the region and transpole, the website for public transport in the region doesn't either. Or I missing something ?

How can I get to the airport ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [official website](http://www.lille.aeroport.fr/getting-to-the-airport/shuttle/) and there's nothing else but the Shuttle. This is a very small airport in Lesquin and has very little to do with Lille. If you really don't want this Shuttle then the closest train station is Gare De Lesquin less than 3km away so a cab shouldn't be horribly expensive.

This is a typical farce in France. The Basel Mulhouse Freiburg airport (which should be avoided at all costs), for example, has no direct connection from Mulhouse *at all*.